# How to use ssis package in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2012

I have created ssis data source in ssrs. but when i am trying create dataset its returning below error. Please help.

===================================

An error occurred while connecting to the data source. Only the text-based query designer will be available. (Microsoft SQL Server Report Designer)

===================================

The selected data extension SSIS is not installed or cannot be loaded.  Verify that the selected data extension is installed on the client for local reports and on the report server for published reports. (Microsoft.ReportingServices.Designer.Controls)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Data.Server.DbConnectionOpener.CreateConnection()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Data.Server.DbConnectionOpener.CreateAndOpenConnection(CachedCredentials creds, PromptMode promptMode, ExceptionHandlingMode exceptionHandlingMode)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Data.Server.QueryManager.CreateAndOpenConnection(PromptMode promptMode, ExceptionHandlingMode exceptionHandlingMode)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Data.Server.QueryManager.CreateAndOpenConnection()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Data.Server.RsConnectionInfo.CreateAndOpenConnection()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.Query.TryCreateConnectionAndCommand(IDbConnection& connection, IDbCommand& command, Exception& exceptionError)

Comment: What are you doing mixing up SSIS and SSRS?  It won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to use SSIS data sources in SSRS.   SSRS uses its own data sources.   Create them in SSRS.